# How to write filter for a reactive Spring Integration flow?

Tags: spring-integration, project-reactor, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using RSocket as `InboundGateway` in my integration flow, using interaction model `REQUEST_CHANNEL`. It emits a `Flux` of my business objects.

I am able to "decorate" these objects using RSocket `OutboundGateways`, but i'm unable to add a filter or router step in my `IntegrationFlow`.

`GenericSelector` expects boolean, so i couldn't use it for the `Flux`. Similar situation for `recipientFlow`. Googling for days now also didn't help.

Are there any examples for this use-case, or do i need to use `split()` to fall back to the objects?

Thanks for any hints!

(I have a large number of objects, that's why i'd like to build a fully reactive flow.)

**Update**

After struggling with this and reading about the topic I now start to understand that I will have a hard time to build a reactive flow as long as both the start and the end of it is blocking (Terradata -> flow -> Oracle)

So i kind-of "withdraw" this question and exploring efficient options to run the flow in a regular, blocking way.

I hope to return to reactive streams soon.

Thanks again for the hints.

**Update 2**

Returned to reactive streams. Now i see (a bit better) the point of reactive streams, and i also see that in my huge flux (with >500k events/object) will not work with filter. It must be implemented as a handler. CPU and memory usage and also processing speed is great.

Answer (score 1):

Would be great to see some of your code, but it sounds like your payload from the `RSocketInboundGateway` is a `Flux`. So, yes the `split()` is OK choice in this case to emit every item in the `Flux` as an individual message for downstream processing.
The output channel of this `split()` could be a `FluxMessageChannel` to have a consumer of this splitter result as a reactive one.

If you don't like `split()`, you can look into a `transform()` against `Flux` payload:

```
.<Flux<String>, Flux<String>>transform((flux) -> flux.map(String::toLowerCase))
```

So, then you case use a `filter()` from the `Flux` API.

The `route()` is a Spring Integration operation to decide to where to send the message next. Kinda branching. Not sure if there is something similar in `Flux`, but if you still need to do a routing based on the items in the `Flux`, then only the mentioned before `split()` can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Indeed it is a Flux, as i wanted to exploit backpressure "feature" in the flow. Nevertheless i still have no solution. After the split, i can't build another Flux, and if i send the message as a GenericMessage, RSocket insists on REQUEST_STREAM mode. I see it should be also fine, so i make some more adjustments there, and come back here with results.

Comment: To build a `Flux` payload back from Spring Integration flow, you need to use look into a `FluxAggregatorMessageHandler`.